# Cloud storage architecture/solution for photos with tags/labels

Tags: android, ios, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, cloud

I plan to create a photo storage app on both Android and iOS operating systems. 
Each stored photo on the cloud should be associated with multiple tags/labels so that my app users on Android and iOS can sync their photos seamlessly with associated tags/categories/labels. Photo storage, preferably, should be encrypted.

What should be the ideal architecture for this use-case? Which cloud platform/APIs would be suitable so that I can have common infrastructure for Android and iOS apps? I will prefer solutions which are light on pocket as well because my apps would be free (may be with some in app purchases) on both the platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Any photo storage solution, if successful, will involve storage costs and data transfer costs. So, do not assume it will be a "light on pocket" venture!

Also, there are plenty of cross-platform photo services available, so your app would need to be distinctive in some way.

Encryption can be handled in-transit by using SSL, and at-rest by using Server-Side Encryption (all handled by the cloud service).

Your application would be responsible for things like:

- User authentication (but you could use cloud services to assist)
- Tracking which photos belong to which user (store this information in a cloud database)
- Storing tags, categories, labels
- Performing photo searches (You could use Elasticsearch for much of this)

I'm not going to recommend a specific service (that's up to you!), but I'll mention that the cloud part is likely to be easier than creating a front-end app for both Android and iOS.

Comment: Thanks a lot John. For storing tags/labels, isn't it a good idea for cloud services to manage them (not sure which all providers actually offer this)

Comment: Tags/labels are just data. They go in a database. A cloud service can provision the database for you, but _what_ you store in it is totally your own creation. Elasticsearch is very good at storing Key/Value pairs and doing very fast search, so it's probably something for you to investigate (even if only for search). Or DynamoDB if you just need to store data (but it's not good for searching). So, the combination of the two might work well.